# MUI v5: How can I auto focus form inputs with errors?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make my form accessible.

Here is my sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-material-ui-textfield-forked-0xh13?file=/src/App.tsx

My requirements are the following:

1. Upon submitting a form with validation errors, the 1st input with an error should be focused

Exactly like this form: https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/web/components-examples/forms/

Is there an option in material ui to achieve this?

This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { Form, Field } from "react-final-form";

const required = (value: string) =>
  value ? undefined : "This field cannot be blank";

const App = () => (
  <Form
    onSubmit={(form_data) => console.log(form_data)}
    render={({ handleSubmit, submitting }) => (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field
          name="line1"
          validate={required}
          render={({ input, meta }) => (
            <TextField
              {...input}
              placeholder="Required"
              label="Required"
              helperText={meta.error}
              error={meta.touched && meta.error}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Field
          name="line2"
          render={({ input, meta }) => (
            <TextField
              {...input}
              placeholder="Optional"
              label="Optional"
              helperText={meta.error}
              error={meta.touched && meta.error}
            />
          )}
        />
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Save</button>
      </form>
    )}
  />
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a plugin for react-final-form called final-form-focus. I don't think there's anything for MUI

https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-material-ui-textfield-forked-vep9e?file=/src/App.tsx